# Only allow one user on system to be SSH'd into

Tags: server, 16.04, ssh, users, port-forwarding

I have two users on my server, `myuser` and `otheruser`.
I want people to only be able to ssh into `otheruser`, and not `myuser`.
I have `openssh-server` installed, and port 22 forwarded.

When I run:

```
$ ssh otheruser@127.0.0.1
```

it works, however, if I run:

```
$ ssh myuser@127.0.0.1
```

it still works.

I don't want it to work, however.
**What do I add to my `sshd_config` to make it only accept one user?**

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Edit your config file `sudo nano /etc/ssh/sshd_config` (or use vim, kwrite, whatever editor instead of nano)
Add this line `AllowUsers otheruser` and possibly `DenyUsers myuser`
Save and close sshd_config file
Reboot your machine or restart SSH service `sudo systemctl restart sshd`
AllowUsers

This keyword can be followed by a list of user name patterns, separated by spaces.If specified, login is allowed only for user names that match one of the patterns.`*' and`?' can be used as wildcards in the patterns.Only user names are valid; a numerical user ID is not recognized.By default, login is allowed for all users.If the pattern takes the form USER@HOST then USER and HOST are separately checked, restricting logins to particular users from particular hosts.

DenyUsers

This keyword can be followed by a list of user name patterns, separated by spaces.Login is disallowed for user names that match one of the patterns.`*' and`?' can be used as wildcards in the patterns.Only user names are valid; a numerical user ID is not recognized.By default, login is allowed for all users.  If the pattern takes the form USER@HOST then USER and HOST are separately checked, restricting logins to particular users from particular hosts.

Answer (score 0):

My quick solution was to add at the end of `/etc/ssh/sshd_config`

```
AllowUsers allowedInnerSubnetUser@192.168.0.0/24 sshUzerFromWWW@*
```

Where :

- `allowedInnerSubnetUser` is the user I use from my inner subnet
- `sshUzerFromWWW` from outside